# How to include I-134 when filing I-539 online?

Tags: usa, visa

I would like to file an I-539 application online for my friend to extend her stay under a B-2 visa. The USCIS website states that this can be done online, but I would like to include an I-134 Affidavit of Support as well for a stronger application. The USCIS website states that the I-134 should be paper filed. How can we file the I-539 online while also including the I-134?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same question.

Comment: No I didn't file